# How can I add scaled catergorical data back to orginal dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm a bit confused with transforming and reverse_tranforming different types of data.  I have a dataframe with numerical and categorical columns.

1. Taking data frame and converting categorical values to numerical
2. Taking the new data frame and scaling it.
3. Running my model on it.
4. Trying to convert it back(unscaled + converting numerical categorical data back to strings)

The problem is I get steps 1-3 working but I'm not sure how to convert the caterogical data back. I can convert the dataframe so it's not scaled anymore(reversing step 2) but not sure how to re-add the column names.

Here's a example, original data:

```
     totalRevenue Exchange  costOfRevenue
0    2.601740e+11   NASDAQ   1.617820e+11
1    2.601740e+11   NASDAQ   1.617820e+11
2    2.655950e+11   NASDAQ   1.637560e+11
3    2.655950e+11   NASDAQ   1.637560e+11
```

After converting and converting back, I have

```
[[2.60174e+11 0.00000e+00 1.61782e+11]
 [2.60174e+11 0.00000e+00 1.61782e+11]
 [2.65595e+11 0.00000e+00 1.63756e+11]
 [2.65595e+11 0.00000e+00 1.63756e+11]
```

Here's my code:

```
catergoryEncoder = OrdinalEncoder()
cleanData['Exchange'] = catergoryEncoder.fit_transform(X_train['Exchange'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
unscaled = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled)
```

The unscaled output simply outputs what I displayed above. I think a few of the challenges I'm facing are, I start with a pandas data frame but after transformation, I have a NumPy array which isn't clear to me how to convert the "exchange" column back.

I know the command to convert the catergorical data back, it's : `catergoryEncoder.inverse_transform(np.asarray(unscaled.Exchange).reshape(-1, 1))` but I'm getting the below error(I suspect because column names are being lost when scaling/unscaling):

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'Exchange'
```

What can I do to convert this easily back/forth? Also am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: Hey, did you try to use the [inverse transform function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.inverse_transform) of the OrdinalEncoder on your unscaled data ?

Comment: @BruceSwain Thank you Bruce. I'm not sure how to apply it. I should mention I know the command that would work - catergoryEncoder.inverse_transform(np.asarray(unscaled.Exchange).reshape(-1, 1)) But it's not working, I suspect because it's on a np frame that has no concept of the original header. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question: why do you get this error ? Your OrdinalEncoder has been trained using a numpy array obtained from the values of a pandas Serie.

As you commented, ( are the reshape really necessary here ? ) (np.asarray should not be necessary as [fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.fit_transform) already gives you a numpy array)

```
catergoryEncoder.inverse_transform(np.asarray(unscaled.Exchange))
```

will result in an error, because a numpy array as no notion of columns names. What you should instead do, is get back your Exchange data by [index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) :

```
catergoryEncoder.inverse_transform(unscaled[:,1])
```

With 1 being the index of the columns you want to select. This should give you back your original data.

Now, on the proper/clean way to implement such things, [Pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline) style is the way to go ([example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-mixed-types-py)).

PS: using [One Hot Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) should remove the need to scale your data, as all the values are encoded between 0 and 1.

**EDIT**

To answer your comments, see a complete example below :

Let's start with a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numeric':[0,1,2,3,4,5],'Categorial1':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],'Categorial2':['A','C','A','C','B','C']})
   Numeric Categorial1 Categorial2
0        0           A           A
1        1           A           C
2        2           A           A
3        3           B           C
4        4           B           B
5        5           B           C
```

Now, applying your encoder :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
encoder = OrdinalEncoder()
#dtype 'O' mean that columns is of type object, this will get all your non numeric data
categorial_column = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'O'] 
df[categorial_column] = encoder.fit_transform(df[categorial_column])
```

Note that if you want to operate with numpy array instead of a DataFrame, you can "save" the index of your categorial columns with :

```
categorial_index = np.where(df.columns.isin(categorial_column))
n_categorial = len(categorial_column)
df.values[:,categorial_index].reshape(-1,n_categorial)
```

Giving you the following (with the full dataframe):

```
   Numeric  Categorial1  Categorial2
0        0          0.0          0.0
1        1          0.0          2.0
2        2          0.0          0.0
3        3          1.0          2.0
4        4          1.0          1.0
5        5          1.0          2.0
```

Then the scalling you already done:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df)
unscaled = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled)
```

Then going back to a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(unscaled, columns=df.columns)
df[categorial_column] = encoder.inverse_transform(df[categorial_column])
```

giving you back :

```
   Numeric Categorial1 Categorial2
0      0.0           A           A
1      1.0           A           C
2      2.0           A           A
3      3.0           B           C
4      4.0           B           B
5      5.0           B           C
```

Now you could fit all the preprocessing steps into some function or a sklearn pipeline and be done with it !

Comment: Thank you so much Bruce!  When I run your example I get this error - ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 3.  3.  3. ... 10. 10. 10.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Also, this works when there is one category, When there is more, should I be manually selecting columns? I was hoping there was a more dynamic way to do this(I'm new to this so not sure if it exists).

Comment: This seemed to work, catergoryEncoder.inverse_transform(unscaled[:,1].reshape(-1,1)) but I still need to convert it back into the pandas dataframe